# Bootstrap checkbox value passed correctly but not showed in the box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a frustrating issue since last week. I am using a bootstrap checkbox inside a modal that I want to prefill with either true or false depending on the user selection for that boolean field. Even though I can get the value correctly, I can not get the tick on the checkbox working.

**modal.html**

```html
<div class="input-group">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="active">
          Active
          <span>
              <input class="form-check-input" name="activeCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="active" onclick="handleCheckboxClick()">
          </span>
     </label>
</div>
```

**handleCheckboxClick.js**

```javascript
$('.form-check-input').change(function () {
    var check = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(check === true) {
        $('#active').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#active').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

**jQuery that prefills the modal**

```javascript
$('#modal-edit-config').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#classname').focus();
    var selectedId = confId;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getConfig',
        data: {configId: selectedId},
        success: function(data){
            var config = data;
            if(config != null) {
                $('#id').val(config.id);
                $('#className').val(config.className);
                console.log(config.active);
                config.active ? $('#active').attr('checked', true).change() : $('#active').attr('checked', false).change();
            }
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error getting the audit configId");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried both with prop() and attr() but, it doesn't work.
The js function works perfectly fine but when the modal pops up the prefilled value of the checkbox even though it is correct, it is not corresponding to the tick or untick in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

### For regular checkboxes

You should use the proper HTML semantics with `.form-check` wrapper as described in [Forms > Checkboxes & Radios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios):

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
      Check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

*As such, our `<input>`'s and `<label>`'s are sibling elements as opposed to an `<input>` within a `<label>`. This is slightly more verbose as you must specify id and for attributes to relate the `<input>` and `<label>`.*

---

### For custom checkboxes

To point you in the right direction you should read the section [Custom forms > checkboxes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#checkboxes).
Please note a label and input pairing wrapped in a div comes with a **specific order**.
The input goes first and is not wrapped by the label.

The reason is simple once you realize an input is an HTML element and they do not support "pseudo elements" `:before` and `:after`. These "pseudo class selectors" are required to introduce custom design on checkboxes/radios and so on.

**Trivial and simplified CSS selector:**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before { content: '✓' }
```

Otherwise there's no direct solution to reverse this selector like `label input[type="checkbox"]:checked`.

With that said, HTML is capable of handling your states by itself. No need for the handleCheckboxClick.js. You can then use `.prop()` to select by default in the ajax handler.

---

If you need to change the order visualy, you can introduce something like `.custom-checkbox-reverse`.

```css
.custom-checkbox-reverse .custom-control-label::before,
.custom-checkbox-reverse .custom-control-label::after {
    left: auto;
    right: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Label after the checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-reverse">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Label before the checkbox</label>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/1y8re02q/)** to play around and enhance the padding for example as well.

---

A revision on the JavaScript part:

```
// what to expect here? 
// should be sufficient to check if it has an id
// perhaps something else we can check? like config.status? Only you know at this point
// in fact it should always return the object or enter the error function
var checkboxState = false; // default
if(config && config.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    $('#id').val(config.id);
    $('#className').val(config.className);
    console.log(config.active); // expecting a boolean value
    checkboxState = !!config.active; // double bang operator to make sure it's a boolean value
}

$('#active').prop('checked', checkboxState);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I adjusted the HTML semantics as you mentioned and removed the handler function from input. Now the value doesn't change neither with .prop() nor with .attr() and still the issue with the unchecked box is there. Should i attach the CSS selector somewhere. I dint quite understand this point.

Comment: 1. Make sure your id "active" is unique on the page. 2. Verify you see the `console.log(config.active)` 3.  simplify to `$('#active').prop({ checked: config.active })` 4. verify in the console directly => `$('#active').prop('checked')` 5. compare CSS to the jsfiddle

Comment: 1. yes its unique. 2. yes i see it and the value its correct. 3. done as well. 4. When the config.active is true the selector is still false.If i manually clicked it and make it true its again icompatible with the original correct value that it should have. Maybe the .change() can help?  5. there is no CSS attached to my file :)

Comment: 4. Not entirely sure if I understand your feedback here. 5. Aren't you using Bootstrap? 6. Are you using React?

Comment: I am new to this sorry, i found it bootstrap.css, right? The prefilling its not working and the checkbox keeps its previous value without taking into consideration the selector value. I hope its more clear now.

Comment: What do you mean: "the selector is still false"? `$('#active')` should not be false or how do you mean?

Comment: `console.log("active -> " + config.active);  ` `console.log("selector -> "  + $('#active').prop('checked')); ` they should have the same value. But they don't.

Comment: More info on [what to expect](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) for `prop()`. Perhaps try with `$('#active').prop({ checked: !!config.active })` which is the double bang operator to convert to boolean values.

Comment: Please revise my edit. Big question, what are the possible values of config.active?

Comment: I solved it by using `$(".form-check-input") ` insted of the `$("#active")` . Which is super weird because there was the only one with that id in that html file of the modal. Thanks for your valuable help !

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes change their visual "checked" status based on the existence of the attribute name itself, not its setting -- according to [dev.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked): checked, Boolean; if present, the checkbox is toggled on by default

```html
<p>Checkbox checked="true"</p>
<input type="checkbox" checked="true">
<p>Checkbox checked="false"</p>
<input type="checkbox" checked="false">
<p>Checkbox (no checked attr)</p>
<input type="checkbox">
```

You should update your checkbox generation JS to leave out the attribute itself: `$('#active').attr('checked', false)` will show a checked checkbox.

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can use `:checked` and it will target the property instead of the attribute.

Comment: That's opening a bucket of worms with extra code, especially for screen readers and ARIA attributes.

Comment: You are referring to use-cases where labels are omitted: see the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#without-labels) on this.

Comment: I think the issue is `$('#active').attr('checked', false)` adds the checked attr to the input making it appear checked in visual representation when it shouldn't be checked: "when the modal pops up the prefilled value of the checkbox even though it is correct it is not corresponding to the tick or untick in the UI."

Comment: @TimVermaelen I had to look up `.prop` -- my answer was suggesting a bad edit

Comment: From what I can interpret, it's more a visual bug than an attr or prop bug. Pasting his HTML in a Bootstrap Fiddle doesn't even show a checkbox. The handleCheckbox is an attempt to work around this. Probably some CSS too which wasn't mentioned. We'll wait for the OP's feedback to see who's right ;)

Comment: @Coll  Yes indeed this in more of a visual bug both .attr() and .prop(). The issue is that the value doesn't change with these function only with the handler function that i created.